# Parameter value filling with quick responses in messenger

Tags: dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger-bot

I have created a bot using Dialogflow (api.ai) and integrated it with Facebook messenger. I want to get the `parameter` values from user: like city, date (today, tomorrow) by using the quick reply feature of messenger, where user is presented with select-box like options, and can tap on one of the options. The required `parameter` receives the user-tapped value, saving the user from typing it manually.

I cannot find anywhere in documentation any way to fill up `parameter` values (slots) using quick replies. There is an option to give quick replies in `response` section, but the `response` section is called on fulfilment, and if I take user input in `response`, then I have to create another follow up intent to process the user-response further, because the current intent gets fulfilled after response.

If I add quick replies in the response section, then I have to create multiple levels of follow-up intents. Ex: I take city input in one intent, and give two options to user (like New York, Delhi). Then I have to create two follow up intents, each for handling one reply (New York and Delhi), and then for each follow up intent, I will have to create more follow up intents to get more parameter inputs. Below is the flow diagram of this case. --->

[image]

This can get pretty complex when more levels are added! Amazon Lex has this feature of filling slots using quick replies. Can't I just fill up parameter values directly using the quick replies like Lex?

Comment: you can ask for multiple parameters in single intent itself by defining [tag:prompts], present next to [tag:IS_LIST] in the parameters block similar to Amazon Lex.

Comment: yes, I am asking for multiple parameters using prompts, but I don't want user to type the input. According to dialogflow documentation of "is List" -> This is ideal for situations where a user’s input contains an enumeration, like “I would like apples, bananas, and oranges.” Doing this isn't showing a quick reply prompt in messenger.

Comment: I agree on your intepretation @Rishabh, the documentation certainly doesn't explain how to use the Quick replies phrases as input to parameter values :-( Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to go this far. There is a simple way of using entities & prompts in dialogflow.com. The workflow can be: `Weather(intent)->quick reply(New york/Delhi)->City(intent) use entities here->quick reply(Today/Tomorrow)->Use different intents here for today & tomorrow as you will have different responses`. You don't need to create different intents unless you have different responses. `User says` can have different parameters for which you can define different prompts as well. This will again reduce your complexity of creating follow-up intents. Let me know if you need more explanation on this.